# Setting the style of the items in a ExtJS 4 combo box

Tags: css, extjs, combobox, sencha-architect

I am building this web application and I have a combo box with several items in it. I am able to style the field and the label properly by using fieldCls and labelCls respectively. However, I also want to style the dropdown items so that they'd look the same as the field value.

I looked over the internet and I [found this blog](http://tpodolak.com/blog/2013/03/19/extjs-changing-style-of-items-in-dropdownlist/) which uses the tpl property of the combobox to change the style of the dropdown items. He also uses an existing style class defined in a css file for the style. I tried to do this for my combobox but I don't see a plain "tpl" property. I tried to add the `fieldSubTpl`, and Sencha Architect gave me this template of sorts to work with:

```
fieldSubTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
     '<div class="{hiddenDataCls}" role="presentation"></div>',
     '<input id="{id}" type="{type}" {inputAttrTpl} class="{fieldCls} {typeCls} {editableCls}" autocomplete="off">',
     '<tpl if="value"> value="{[Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(values.value)]}"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="name"> name="{name}"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="placeholder"> placeholder="{placeholder}"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="size"> size="{size}"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="maxLength !== undefined"> maxlength="{maxLength}"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="readOnly"> readonly="readonly"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="disabled"> disabled="disabled"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="tabIdx"> tabIndex="{tabIdx}"</tpl>',
     '<tpl if="fieldStyle"> style="{fieldStyle}"</tpl>',
     '/>',
     {
         disableFormats: true
     }
```

However I am not sure how to configure this and I tried to use the code the blog above used, substituting my own style in but to no avail.

It seems that they changed the way tpl is used for comboboxes and I can't find a reference for what I have.

Comment: In Sencha Architect, you can't do everything you can do in ExtJS. Sencha Architect is a subset, I estimate it at somewhere between 5% and 15% of what's possible in ExtJS.

Comment: I see. Would you have the slightest idea on how to make this work..?

Comment: That's really easy: Drop Architect.

Answer (score 3):

You can style dropdown list items in your combobox with [Ext.form.field.ComboBox.tpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-tpl) config.

Check this [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bpq) with working example.

You can read description of how to use it in [Ext.view.BoundList.tpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-cfg-tpl) as Ext.view.BoundList is a picker component of Ext.from.field.ComboBox (not sure why this description is not dupicated in Ext.form.field.ComboBox.tpl).

*As more complex solution you can overrite [Ext.view.BoundList.tpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/source/BoundList.html#Ext-view-BoundList)*